# ExpressionEngine template will not output empty JSON array

Tags: ruby, json, expressionengine

I'm creating JSON in an ExpressionEngine template and pointing the Ruby JSON library at the relevant URL. The template looks like this:

```
[
{exp:mylib:mytag channel="mychannel" backspace="1"}
  {"entry_id":"{entry_id}","title":"{title}"},
{/exp:mylib:mytag}
]
```

When the tag returns data, everything is fine, my Ruby code works perfectly with the array of objects. However, when the tag returns no data (because there are no appropriate entries), Ruby complains that the json string is not the required 2 octets in length. I would expect the output to be `[]`, i.e. an empty but valid JSON array. However, visiting the URL in Firefox/firebug and wget confirms that the response coming back from the URL is zero bytes in length, with status 200 OK.

I tested further by creating a template without tags and just a pair of empty square brackets, with the same result: zero bytes.

Is a pair of empty square brackets somehow a reserved token in the EE template language? Is there some clever optimisation going on that assumes that no-one could ever want a pair of square brackets in an html page?

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing your own add-on, or using the built-in ExpressionEngine tags?

Using the native channel entries queries, you can use a [if_no_results](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results) conditional tag to control what gets output when there are no matching results:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name"}
    {if no_results} ...{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Many third-party add-ons also support the same type of `{if_no_results}` conditional.

You might also have a look at the third-party [ExpressionEngine JSON](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/json) add-on, which may be able to give you some inspiration on how to approach your situation.

Comment: It's not about the output of the tags. A template that consists of literally just the two characters '[]' (_no_ tags) comes out blank when processed by EE.

Comment: What [*template type*](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/new_template.html#template-type) do you have configured in the EE Template Preferences Manager — is PHP enabled?

Comment: Will use your suggestion of an {if no_results} conditional.